# Having font color option in Stack Overflow question editor

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, editor

Stack Overflow provides good tools in the question editor, like "Links" and "Styling".

Another thing that for me would be nice is a color selector. Although an HTML editor is available, a direct click on tool would be good, and users can select different colors, as for marking errors in their program with red, and more important data with blue.

Comment: @CATboardBETA adding a bounty isn't going to see this reconsidered. Write a new post explaining why this should be reconsidered and the reasons that have changed in the meantime to make this succesfull today.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[image]

---

No, seriously. Having colors would enable people to abuse them. Of course, we also have a possibility for people to abuse headlines or subscripts, but colors can be very distracting if not used correctly.

In order to highlight stuff, we already have **boldface** and *emphasized text*. If you can't make clear what the error is, for example, you probably need to rewrite a bit.

Comment: I don't know. Some bad posters will bold everything, but that doesn't happen very often. It's not like people act like SO is myspace.

Comment: But it is essentially useless. There I agree.

Comment: I am asking a question where I have to post a terminal output for a certain issue, and this output is coloured. Even if it's not a must, it would be nice to be able to render the colouring in my question.

Comment: I wanted anti-emphasis though; to grey my text to make it more of a side note.

Comment: @minseong I fear that's only going to make it harder to read. Like in normal writing, you could simply make it a footnote.

Comment: @slhck The point is to make it harder to read, and it's more of a header-style message. But yes, I agree completely with your answer about all other colors.

Comment: I wanted to make a **Warning:** label yellow or red .. but ok

Comment: Well, I imagine this could be used on philosophy and puzzle. Maybe somewhere else too.

Comment: It's all good and dandy until you switch to dark theme, where bold is barely noticeable.

Comment: For some fonts, it's impossible to use italics. Having the possibility to use colors should be handy sometimes.

Comment: Colors are really helpful in math. For example, think you have this set of numbers: 1, 9, 108, 54. You want to say that 10 in 108 should be added to 9. And 5 in 54 should be added to 8 in 108. By bolding the desired numbers you can't say this. You have to color them. For example, 9 and 10 be blue; and 8 & 5 be red.

Answer (score 26):

I would like to give an example of a question where colours are used.

[image]

I think if used cautiously, colours can help to underline the content of a text very effectively. Of course, the opposite can happen as well; but to me the risk should not be too big.

Comment: Much agreed. Sad that we can't appeal this?

Comment: Nope, nope. Colors do not add any value here. You can as well use **Pro:** and **Contra:**. If you saturate your text with bolded and emphasized text, then you would need colors too. But in that case, you should probably reformat your text anyway, instead of adding more formatting.

Comment: @Olli: Bolding it doesn't even resemble the same effect. The green is clearly meant to draw the eye towards "positive" items, while the red is clearly meant for "negative" items. The eye is already drawn towards the words-as-headings by the giant whitespace around them, making the bold style largely unnecessary. Color-coding, on the other hand, can be immensely useful in reading comprehension. Hence why, for a very relevant example, code editors often have color-coding. And is the issue that bold and italic styles are already very overloaded in semantic meaning. Adding color eases this burden.

Answer (score 22):

I don't see any value such a feature would give except for adding complexity and the potential for rather horrific looking questions.

Answer (score 21):

This would be particularly useful in providing answers where color is important, without having to opt for screenshots.

An obvious example is making error text clear from normal output; most systems will show console errors in red-on-black to distinguish them from the regular output in white-on-black.

The only argument against seems to be fear of misuse.
Any feature can be abused; that's not a reason not to implement something.  Just ensure that guidelines on when it's acceptable to use are made clear in the guidelines.  The SO community are very good at self-policing, so users will likely quickly learn what's appropriate & fall in with the guidelines.

Answer (score 10):

> as for marking errors in their program with red

In that case, it wouldn't be possible to write code that is formatted as code, and contemporary mark a line with a specific color.
Apart that use case, I don't think there are use cases where colors make the post clearer. What is more important in a post is its content, not the color used for the text, or the background.

Comment: This is excellent and should be promoted much more! Highlighting one char / word in code is totally useful, but also extremely rarely seen. Seems like nobody knows about this feature.

Comment: thanks; this is what I was looking for..

Answer (score 8):

1) It's already possible to put colors by abusing MathJax for the stacks that support it.

```
\$\color{red}{\text{WARNING}}\$
```

#### Example rendering

[image: red warning]

2) A really motivated user could also upload an image of colored text anyway -- just like they could post a unicorn riding a rainbow, if they think the post looks somehow better that way.

Because it's possible to do it by hackish ways, I personally think that it would be fine to allow it natively. Apart from spam posts, we don't see many pictures of unicorns or any abusive content. We don't even see many posts **ENTIRELY WRITTEN IN BOLD AND ALL CAPS**. So I think we should just trust the users for colors as well.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, but thanks. I find this thread and that this feature was declined, unbelievable. There is huge communication clarity value in being able to drive readers to certain text within the context of a larger blob of text via color.

Comment: I think they actually made this impossible, since your post. Too bad, it was my go-to work around :\

Comment: @RaxAdaam [works fine](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15134/64206) AFAICT—on the stacks with MathJax. Just be sure to un-escape the dollars (not sure why this post has these extra backslashes).

Comment: @Ruslan I'm primarily a [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com) user. The backslashes are required on that stack.

Comment: The reason this didn't work for @DougSmythies is that you have excessive slashes in your formatting. It should have been ```$\color{red}{\text{WARNING}}$```.

Comment: But how did you bold the phrase "Example rendering" with three hashes?!

Answer (score 3):

Our brains have millions of years of evolutionary adaptation to visual (*i.e.* colour) processing, whereas symbolic processing is a relatively late addition to our daily life...

That point aside, I just wanted to add that a judicious use of colour can call out an especially relevant point in an otherwise long / detailed post: this allows posters to provide all the relevant details, while also allowing other users to quickly navigate the post, without overlooking important details.

Bold and italics *can* do this as well, but only up to a certain point. Eventually (because everything is the same colour), bold type competes with headers (and italics do not make text "jump out" in the same way; not to mention they can be very hard to read).

As for the "people will abuse it" argument. The community already has guidelines for how to post a question (which has far more potential for being misused than colour IMO), and we have community members with the ability to edit posts and manage content. Surely allowing one or two colours is something this community can handle, no?

Comment: I didn't come here to look at a christmas tree, black and white suffices. Not to mention the accesability issues that come with colours and colourblindness.

Comment: @Luuklag -- while you're entitled to your opinion, what you have written here it is not really a response to the points made in my post; rather, it seems you have down-voted my answer simply because you disagree with the proposed feature, which is hardly productive. There's a pretty big difference between "looking at a Christmas tree"  and "including a line of red text" (unless one has a particularly tame tree). And it's not as though accessibility issues begin with the inclusion of colour, but like all the other barriers, this one, too, can be addressed.

Comment: This answer is extremely ableist. You haven't even _considered_ accessibility. Colours are simply not the right tool for any of these jobs. The markdown provided allows us to signal _semantics_ in the post (the resultant formatting is effectively a side effect!) - and colour is not semantics. Period. End of story.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I'm not sure how this answer is "extremely ableist", as pointed out in my previous comment, there are ways of addressing issues introduced for colourblind individuals (e.g. choice of colour, use of texture, development of accessibility overlays that achieve equivalent results _etc_). And yes, Markdown was designed to signal semantics; however, there is no rule that the site need be limited to Markdown. Indeed, we already include other options, like TeX and HTML, that go beyond what Markdown can do, to _facilitate_ communication.

Comment: I've already explained how it is. We're not just talking colourblindness here. What about screenreaders?? But if you have edits pending please apply them to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I don't see an explanation of _how_, I see a label ("This answer is extremely ableist"), and an accusation ("You haven't even _considered_ accessibility."). Then an assertion of opinion ("... not the right tool for any of these jobs") and a fact ("markdown ... signal[s] _semantics_ ... colour is not semantics"). I place great value on creating an inclusive community, but I think we should look at extending functionality for all, instead of limiting it. If you just don't like colour, that's fair, but my finding value in it doesn't make me, _ipso facto_ ableist.

Comment: @RaxAdaam We'll agree to disagree then.