# Stack --color type syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, support

With [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) type questions it would be nice if stack had a way highlight the matched parts, for instance if some like:

```
$ grep --color '[a-z]' <<< '123abc45ef'
123abc45ef
```

It would be nice to have a way to render the matched part say red:

```
$ grep --color '[a-z]' <<< '123abc45ef'
123[match:red]abc[match:end]45[match:red]ef[match:end]
```

Comment: Sorry but your request makes very little sense. Example might help.

Comment: He's talking about extending markdown to basically allow you to change the color of text inside of a code / block quote block, so that matches could be highlighted for easier reading. The request isn't off base, I just don't see a use case where simply indicating what matched or didn't match wouldn't work.

Comment: @TimPost see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135088/regular-expression-does-not-match-symbol/14135152#14135152) here, the second grep is slightly confusing as it highlights blue `He` and `Wo`.

Comment: @sudo_O Ahhh, so what you want is just more granular control of the syntax highlighting?

Comment: @TimPost yes, I think it would be helpful.

Comment: @TimPost: I sense fun there...I'm sure there will be users which completely fail to tag their questions properly and then use that markdown to simulate syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

[A request for allowing users to customise font colours has been requested before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115455/having-font-color-option-in-so-question-editor) and declined. IMHO, rightly so. Considering how some users abuse bold and code markup to highlight portions of text which they think is important, the thought of adding font colours to their bag of tricks makes me cringe.

As for customising the colours used in syntax highlighting, I believe [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) is used so any related feature requests would have to be posted upstream.  However, do note that highlighting is performed based on syntax, not markup, so the sample usage as you've posted in the question is unlikely to be adopted.

In the case of [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135088/regular-expression-does-not-match-symbol/14135152#14135152) where the default highlighting is potentially misleading, a possible compromise would be to disable syntax highlighting (it would however make your `grep --color` example moot). Simply use `<pre>` instead of indenting the code block, or precede the code block with `<!-- language: lang-none -->` (see [syntax highlight language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints/75019#75019)).

If specific text colour is absolutely essential to the post, use a small screenshot.