# Making "wrong code" clearly visible as "wrong" (maybe in red text)

Tags: feature-request

Currently StackOverflow (and maybe all other portals) cannot clearly differ between "good" and "bad" code. So, when quoting a users code it's not really visible what's wrong and what's not. Giving users the possibility to color text red would make some thing much more clear.

Comment: There are better ways to identify wrong code than adding in ugly color effects that will only get abused. Related: [Having font color option in SO question Editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115455/having-font-color-option-in-so-question-editor)

Comment: @animuson But this is downvoted 15 times... I don't think people want this.

Comment: This doesn't work `if a ==== b: print 1`; this does work: `if a == b: print 1`. What's the difference between the codez?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Edge case! But usually this might be useful. Currently the `mysql` vs. `mysqli` issue is a big thing in php on SO, so it might be interesting to mark such fine differences.

Comment: It's not an edge case @Panique; it's words :-)... if you write that something doesn't work then it indicates that it doesn't work... without the need for colouring everything.

Comment: People will just terribly misuse it. As it stands, too many users already abuse the inline code option to highlight random stuff you really want to give them **colors**??

Comment: It's your job to make this not ugly and not-misuseable! All IDEs and coding tools use decent colors to clarify critical errors.

Comment: Actually, no, it's not our job. It's **your** job, because you're the one making the feature request!

Comment: @Panique Stack Overflow is not an IDE or a coding tool. It's a Q&A site.

Answer (score 5):

### 1. LET'S MAKE IT RED

Don't you hate it when users think that **CAPITALIZED BOLD QUESTIONS WILL GET MORE ATTENTION??** Well... I do. And I don't want it to be possible for users to color the whole post or even some parts of the post with an annoying color such as red.

### 2. This is not an IDE

> All IDEs and coding tools use decent colors to clarify critical errors.
>                                                              – Panique

Stack Exchange is not an *IDE*. It simply offers formatting tools to make the code clearer. Trust me; it's already clear enough. Also, when I see colored code, I don't see mistakes or wrong things. I see classes, methods, data types. Mixing errors with the whole thing would be just messed up.

[image]

### 3. Aim for the right solution

Like stated in a comment above, text will always be the best solution here.

> This is good:
>
> ```
> int x = 2 / 2;
> ```
>
> This is wrong:
>
> ```
> int x = 2 / 0;
> ```

Why ? It's more clear (you don't have to think about "hey what is this color's meaning again?") and also, we are not forgetting our [color blind friends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness).

---

I see too many problems here for this to even be considered.

Comment: The other thing I will do, if I'm really worried that people won't read the text, is to add a comment like `// WRONG CODE` or `// this code is broken` to the end of the line. (Obviously using the correct syntax for the language.)