# How can I color text in my post?

Tags: support, design

Is it possible to color some of my text in the post?

I have 2 columns in my question post. I want to show column one as red and column 2 as green.

Is this possible?

Comment: Also asked on [SoftwareRecs.Meta](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/447/can-we-do-colours-in-markdown) with a slightly different use case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible.

There's a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115455/having-font-color-option-in-so-question-editor) for it, but as you can see it was fairly unpopular.